# Como habilitar save en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Buenas tardes estoy desarrollando un ejercicio con *spring boot* al usar **save** no lo reconoce este método y tengo otro ejercicio parecido ahí no tengo este problema, la única diferencia que hice entre los dos ejercicios es que el que me trae erro lo estoy realizando en java 17 y *spring boot* 3 y el otro en java 11 y *spring boot* 2.7, por favor si alguien me ayuda, gracias